# django admin redirect to my custom view

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In my admin I want to put my custom view. When I click on the model name I want to redirect to the custom view not on the list view of the model:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
def get_urls(self):
    urls = super(MyAdmin, self).get_urls()
    csv_urls = patterns('', url(r'^my/url/$', admin.site.admin_view(self.my_view)))

    return csv_urls + urls

def my_view(self, request):
    return render_to_response("my_template.html")
```

I have registered the model with admin.

I see the model name but when I click on it, it's not being redirected to my url to show my view. It is being redirected to normal list view.

How can I redirect my it to my view ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to render a static template, you can put the template in `templates/admin/<app name>/<model name>` and name it `change_list.html`.

Or you can override `changelist_view()` like so:

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     def changelist_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
         return render_to_response("my_template.html")
```

Comment: That is not what i really wanted. I just want when I click to my model name in admin I want it to be redirected to my view.. I would like to put a hyper link on model name where it should be redirected to given value..

Comment: Exactly where do you want this? On the admin index page?

Answer (score 0):

To customise the add/change view of a model that is registered with admin, you can either:

1. overwrite the add/change form by specifying it in the modeladmin.
2. Use a custom field in modeladmin list_display fields that allows html tags so you can generate a clickable link.

Option 1 is the simplest and gives you the advantage that you're using an admin template, inheriting from the admin templates higher up in the template tree. Your code should be similar to:

```
from .forms import MyForm

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = Myform
```

Option 2 allows you to use a completely separate new view. But you have to take care of the permissions yourself, and the template needs to inherit from an admin template if you want to make it look like your 'in the admin'. You can do so by extending `admin/base_site.html`.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from .views import my_view

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['mychangelink']

    def mychangelink(self, obj):
        return '<a href="{0}">Change</a>'.format(reverse(my_view, args=[obj.pk]))
    mychangelink.allow_tags = True
```

Django escapes html by default, that's why you need to allow the tags to actual make it a clickable link. Otherwise it would just be text.